# How to Export search configuration from Site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, central-administration, enterprise-search, search-schema

When i export search configuration from here:

[image]

SearchConfiguration.xml is verry small and not contais all Managed Properties  and another settings.

**Problem is:**

> I added all Managed Properties from Central Administration Search
>   schema. Where i try to export configuration from site collection - xml
>   file does not contain the properties I've added

How to export SearchConfiguration from Central administration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot export search configuration from central administration.

If you want to move the search service application from one environment to another environment, you could back up the search service application and restore it in another environment.

We can back up and restore search service application by PowerShell command or Central Administration.

And the two procedures can back up all of the search components including the databases, the search service configuration, and all of the index files.

More references:

Back up Search service applications in SharePoint 2013.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748635.aspx

Restore Search service applications in SharePoint 2013

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748654.aspx